# Grayscale on only part of an image?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible in css to make only part of an image grayscale?
I have tried using filters to no avail, can't seem to think of any way to accomplish this. Do you have any ideas?

I want to make this image grayed out only under the dark part of this page.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've done something like this before to achieve that...

1. Use a `div` and set its `background-image` to the image.
2. Set the `background-position` and absolutely position it so it appears to be the same image.
3. Use CSS to set the grayscale on the `div`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nc7Vt/).

For the exact thing that you're going for, I might make it have a black background with `opacity` set as required, and a top inset shadow for the top effect.